# "You look like your brother" or "Your brother looks like you"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, expression-choice, conditionals

My friends are always saying stuff like, "You look like your brother
," or "Your brother looks like you." My brother is 4 years younger than me and I really can't see the resemblance; but it got me wondering.  Since I am the elder brother shouldn't it be

> *Your brother looks like you*

since I was born first, rather than

> *You look like your brother*

Comment: Either or neither. It depends entirely on your point of view.

Comment: Generally, if the person had previously met your brother, but was just meeting you, it would be "You look just like your brother".  If they already knew you and were just introduced to your brother, on the other hand, they might say "Your brother looks just like you."

Comment: @HotLicks Good call !

Comment: I remember a speaker once saying that statements like 'You remind me of Charlton Heston' are not very affirming (for 'you'). He suggested 'Charlton Heston reminds me of you'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, but for some reason women are always livid when I say that to them. Especially when they're naked at the time. Some people just can't take a compliment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost getting into a question of philosophy, but both are equally acceptable. In the [Merriam Webster online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look), the second definition given for "look" is

> to seem to be something especially because of appearance

and we can certainly say that your appearance seems like your brother's. In general, "looks like" will always express a transitive relationship, because it means that there is a **similarity** in appearance. The difference between them is the standard of comparison and the focus:

> Your brother looks like you

is a statement about your brother, comparing him to you. As such, it would be more likely to be used when the subject of conversation is your brother, or when the person speaking is more familiar with your appearance than with your brother's.

> You look like your brother

is a statement about your appearance, so it would naturally be used in a situation where the subject of conversation is your own appearance, or when the speaker already knows how your brother looks and has just met you.

It would be possible to respond to the latter statement with a joking "No, he looks like me -- I was born first!" but the fact of your being born first doesn't actually invalidate either of these points of view.